# Python sort using key and lambda, what does lambda do?

Tags: python, lambda

So I have a list of values like so:

```
{
    "values": 
    [
        {
            "date": "2015-04-15T11:15:34",
            "val": 30
        },
        {
            "val": 90,
            "date": "2015-04-19T11:15:34"
        },
        {
            "val": 25,
            "date": "2015-04-16T11:15:34"
        }
    ]
}
```

that I'm parsing in with pythons deafault json parser into a list like so:

```
with open(file) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

values = data["values"]
```

I'm then trying to sort the data by date like so:

```
values.sort(key=lambda values: values["date"])
```

And this works (to my knowledge). My question is why does it work? If I can't access values["date"] then why can I use this lambda function? values can't take a key like "date" only an integer. What I mean by this is I can only access values like so: values[0], values[1], etc... because it's a list not a dictionary. So if this lambda functions equivalent is this:

```
def some_method(values):
    return values[“date”]
```

then this is invalid because values is a list not a dictionary. I can't access values["date"].

So why can I just pass in the date through the function like this? Also if you could explain lambda in depth that would be appreciated. I've read other posts on stack overflow about it but they just don't make sense to me.

Updated question with more information to make the problem more clear.

Comment: Think of a lambda as a short form of a function with an implied return statement, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `lambda` expression is simply a concise way of writing a function. It's especially handy in cases like the one you give where you only need to use the function once, and it needs to be used as an expression (e.g. an argument to a function).

Here's an alternative version of your example, using `def` statement instead of a `lambda` expression:

```
def keyfunc(values):
    return values["date"]
values.sort(key=keyfunc)
```

That's two lines longer, and leaves behind an extra variable in the current namespace. If the lambda version is just as clear as the `def` version, it's generally a better choice.

It looks like your confusion may come from the extra use of the name `values` in the function. That's simply a poorly chosen argument name. The `list.sort` method will call the `key` function once for each value in the list, passing the value as the first positional argument. That value will be bound to whatever variable name is used in the function declaration (regardless of whether it's a `def` or a `lambda`). In your example, a better name might be `val` or `item`, since it's going to be just a single item from the `values` list. The name could really be whatever you want (and indeed, `values` works fine, it just looks confusing). This would be clearer:

```
values.sort(key=lambda val: val["date"])
```

Or:

```
def keyfunc(val):
    return val["date"]
values.sort(key=keyfunc)
```

Comment: Sorry exercises was a typo the correct variable to sort is values. But that's the thing. I can't access values["date"] through the code but this lambda function still works. Why? As in, values is a list not a dictionary.

Comment: Values isn't referring to your list, it is the argument to a new function, thus it will mask that variable. It could be called `x` or `element` or whatever.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address the confusing parameter name in addition to the difference between a `lambda` and a normal function.

Comment: Oh I see so what's actually going on is that 'val' is one of the elements in the list 'values' (which is a dictionary that I can access using val["date"] or val["val"]. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: OHHH I get it thanks a bunch. So much more helpful than TigerhawkT3.