# Sort by last 3 digits

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list like:

```
barcode = ["13350V1","13350V10","13350V2","13350V20"]
```

I want to sort this list based on the last three digits, so the result would be:

```
newbarcode = ["13350V1","13350V2","13350V10","13350V20"]
```

Now I am able to do this using the script below, but I am not exactly sure what does this mean (x: `str(x)[-3]`) and appreciate your help in this regard.

```
newbarcode = sorted(barcode, key=lambda x: str(x)[-3])
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to sort for last 3 digits and not starting at V?

Comment: `[-3]` is one character only. You probably want `[-3:]` (note the colon)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914387/python-sort-using-key-and-lambda-what-does-lambda-do might help, it discusses using key and lambda in python sorting.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I want to sort the list based on the last three digits to get a result of v1,v2,v10, v20, so yes you are correct.

Comment: @Corralien this will result in
["13350V10","13350V1","13350V20","13350V2"]

Comment: That's not a very good example. In the first two examples the most significant character is the 0 before V. In the last 2 examples because the number after V has two digits the sort uses V as the most significant character. Are you sure this is how you want to sort this SN? Or you want to sort by the digits after V?

Comment: @Parya. Check my answer, I think it's probably what you expect.

Comment: @ThomasWeller [-3:] this will work but what does exactly mean?

Comment: I want to sort by digits after V actually, but the serial number I have is not 01, 02, ..., 10, 20. Instead, it is 1,2,...,10,20

Comment: x[n] is indexing. It gives you 1 element of a sequence. x[n:m] is called slicing. It gives you elements n to m. if m is omitted, it will give you the elements from n to the end

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: @ThomasWeller

so in case of this 
newbarcode = sorted(barcode, key=lambda x: int(x.split("V")[-1]))

[-1] means the last digit?

and also in case of 

newbarcode = sorted(barcode, key=lambda x: str(x)[-3:])

the last 3 digits?

Comment: Yes. The negative indexes are a bit surprising when you know other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the position of `V` in the string then sort on all digits after but pad them with 0 to have a natural sort:

```
barcode = ['13350V1','13350V10','13350V2','13350V20']
newbarcode = sorted(barcode, key=lambda x: x[x.rindex('V')+1:].zfill(5))
print(newbarcode)

# Output
['13350V1', '13350V2', '13350V10', '13350V20']
```

**Update**

> What does str(x)[-3] meaning?

Suppose the number `1357900`:

```
>>> n
1357900

# Convert number to string
>>> str(n)
'1357900'

# Now get the third character from the end (negative indexing)
>>> str(n)[-3]
'9'

# Slice the string from the third character from the end to end
>>> str(n)[-3:]
'900'
```

Comment: Using `rindex` is better.

Comment: Thank you @Corralien

what does str(x)[-3] meaning?

Comment: Thank you! So when I write this:

newbarcode = sorted(barcode, key=lambda x: str(x)[-3:])

how will slice translate into sort? is this because of the sorted function? so the above script means to sort it based on the last 3 digits? Is this what it means?

Comment: @Parya. Exactly. The function create this list: `['0V1', 'V10', '0V2', 'V20']` and sort it in the lexicographical order. That's why I used a different function.

Comment: `x[x.rindex('V')+1:].zfill(5))` create a list like this `['00001', '00010', '00002', '00020']` respect the natural order.

Answer (score 0):

For more complex tasks it might be better for you to understand if you create a method instead of a magic one line lambda:

```
def sortbyend(x: str) -> int:    
    pieces = x.split("V")
    last_piece = pieces[-1]
    number = int(last_piece)
    return number

barcode = ["13350V1","13350V2","13350V10","13350V20"]    
newbarcode = sorted(barcode, key=sort_by_end)
print(newbarcode)
```

That way you can understand and test and debug the function individually before it gets used in the `key` property.

Once you understood lambdas and are more familiar with them, you can convert it to a lambda:

```
newbarcode = sorted(barcode, key=lambda x: int(x.split("V")[-1]))
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Python so I do not understand what does x: int(x.split("V")[-1])) mean. You are splitting based on V, why do you need to change it to int or why do you need [-1]?

Comment: `x[-1]` gives you the last element of x

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help. I wish I could accept multiple answers as the soultion. As your method is also correct too.